# solving differential equations in matrix-vector form using odeint in c++

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I am trying to solve a set of linear ordinary differential equations (ODEs) in a matrix form using ODEINT, which is one of the Boost packages.

The problem I am trying to solve has the following form (in MATLAB format):

```
dxdt(1:10) = A1*x(1:10) + B1;

dxdt(11:20) = A2*x(11:20) + B2;
```

where A1 and A2 are constant matrices, and B1 and B2 are constant vectors; "x" are states to solve and "dxdt" are the time derivatives of the states "x". My question is how to program it in c++ using ODEINT. I tried several things I found on the internet but could not find Any proper way to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/examples.html

Have you seen this?

Comment: what are the parameters? Also, write your system in a mathematical form.